# Kickass utility for displaying real-time firewall activity

Tags: networking, monitoring, graphics

I've seen this utility in use, so I know it exists. I've scoured Google for an hour but can't turn up anything besides hosts3d, which isn't it.

This utility would run on a firewall box (or in-line with a gateway). It shows graphically packets being dropped and allowed. The packets would fly in on one side of the screen and bounce back if rejected, but pass to the other side if allowed. I remember it made me think of pong.

Anyone know what I'm talking about?

Comment: So this is it's own OS, or it runs on something; it's firewall software, or it runs against some firewall??

Comment: With any quantity of traffic I'd think that such a display would be overwhelmed.

Comment: @Chris: I believe it runs on an OS and it is not the firewall itself, but I'm not positive.

Comment: I had a few Fireboxen back in 2003-2004, the Windows management application would show a display like this - but it was lines and zones, it didn't really look like Pong.

Obviously, this would only work on Firebox firewalls, and I haven't worked on them in years so I don't know if this feature is still in there.

Comment: I highly doubt this is real but if you find it let me know it would be great to entertain the boss with...

Comment: There is definitely a feature like this for Firebox firewalls, and it's improved a little in recent versions.
From practical experience I'd say that Evan is correct though - even with only a few active users it's very difficult to tell what's happening

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing makes me think of [Fudgie](http://www.fudgie.org/).  I've used stuff like this for monitoring consoles to make logs look fancy.

Comment: Congrats on 10K!